# emacs tells me directory is write-protected

Tags: permissions, emacs

I have come up with an issue when I tried to save a file. I managed to write the intended file but then when I try to save it with the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> the message comes up `Directory / write-protected` How can I save the file?

Answer (score 3):

Wait, you're trying to save a file into the root directory? Are you sure you actually want to do that?

If you're sure, save it as `/sudo::/filename` instead. I don't know much about OSX, but as it's your own machine I'm assuming you have sudo permissions, in which case Emacs will prompt you for your password, and should then write the file.

Comment: That's the weird thing!  I'm not!  It's possible I was before, but I changed the save location to a folder that is definitely fine to write in and emacs is still giving me strife.

Comment: How about `C-x C-w ~/filename RET` to save into your home directory. Does that work?

Comment: This is so useful for jumping into `/etc/` without reverting to launching another session as sudo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to view (`dired`) the directory. Go to the parent directory (pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on `..`) and change the permissions for the directory by pressing <kbd>S-m</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then, you should be able to save the file.

Comment: When I try to do that I get the message "Operation not permitted, /../.file"

Comment: If you do not have the permission to create a file in a directory and you cannot change it, Emacs cannot do anything about it. Ask your system administrator.

Comment: Also, how can I get the directory of a file I haven't saved yet?

Comment: I am the system administrator.  I'm just working on my laptop.  How do I let emacs know that?

Comment: @user1765835: As a system admin, you should be permitted to change permissions on directories. What OS are you running? Do you use ACL's?

Comment: @user1765835: Emacs keeps a "current directory". If you do not specify otherwise, a new file is written to it.

Comment: I'm on a MacBook Pro, OS 10.7.5 so that's Lion.  I don't think I use any ACL's

Answer (score 0):

Start from `emacs -Q`, i.e., no init file (no `~/.emacs`).  It does not sound like you did that.  My guess is that something in your init file is messing things up.

If you have no such problem when you start from `emacs -Q`, then bisect your init file recursively until you find the problematic code.  Quick to do, no matter how big your init file is.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same problem. I had to create a php file within `/opt/lampp/htdocs/test`. `test` is the directory I had created.
Say for example, I had to create `color.php` within it.
I opened the terminal navigated to the location using `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/test` then used `sudo emacs color.php`.

This opened the file in emacs. I could edit and save it.